# react-native - call another function when fetch is over

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, request, fetch

I'm new to React-Native

I have `fetch`, through which I get some data. What I want to do is to call another function or update the state, after the request is over and data is ready. Here is my code.

```
getProducts()
    {
        return fetch(prodUrl, {method: "GET"})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({brandList: responseData.products});
                console.log("Brands State -> : ",this.state.brandList)
            })
            .done();
    }
```

I call this `getProducts()` function in `componentWillMount()` and trying to use fetched data in `render()`.
After I set the state, I can't see the change when I try to `console.log()`, most probably because `fetch()` is async. How can I stop execution of `render()` function  before `fetch()` is over? Or can you recommend any other request type rather then `fetch()` which is sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not because fetch is async, you already have your responseData at that point. It is because setState doesn't change state immediately, so you're console.log is being called before state is being changed. setState has an optional callback as it's second parameter that will be called once set is done being updated, so you can change it like this to see the effect correctly:

```
getProducts()
    {
        return fetch(prodUrl, {method: "GET"})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState(
                  {brandList: responseData.products},
                  () => console.log("Brands State -> : ",this.state.brandList)
                );  
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to "stop" the `render()` function from being executed. You can, however, apply a check in render if the data is available and render a spinner or something else while it is not.

Very rough sketch of how this could look like:

```
render() {
  let component = this.state.brandList ? <ComponentWithData/> : <Spinner/>;
  return component;
}
```